Child component keeps refreshing on useState set
I have a parent component with an  onChange setSearch useState.  I then have another component with params search={search}.  In the child component I have useEffect to call the server with the search query.  It just keeps hammering the server with constant rapid refreshes.  If I comment out the setRepairCentres line, it stops refreshing.
export default function RepairCentreSearch() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    return (
        <>
            <fieldset className="offset-sm-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label className="form-label mb-1" htmlFor="repairCentreSearch">Repair Centre Name</label>
                <input
                    id="repairCentreSearch"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setSearch(e.target.value)
                    }}
                    placeholder="Search for your repair centre"
                />
            </fieldset>
            <div className="col-12">
                <RepairCentreResults search={search}></RepairCentreResults>

export function RepairCentreResults({search}: { search: string }) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [repairCentres, setRepairCentres] = useState<RepairCentreDto[]>([])

    console.log(search)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5193/GetRepairCentres?search=' + search)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((repairCentres : RepairCentreDto[]) => {
                setRepairCentres(repairCentres)
                setIsLoading(false)
            })
    })
    if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>

    return (
        <div className="table-responsive">


Try wrapping RepairCentreSearch using memo

Try this
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5193/GetRepairCentres?search=' + search)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((repairCentres : RepairCentreDto[]) => {
            setRepairCentres(repairCentres)
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
}, [search]);

You should place the "search" dependency, this will make search work only when changes occur.
See react useEffect documentation here
https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

That doesn't work.  I think because search is a constant by this point.

I think I had some staleness to my session.  Refreshing seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!
